# Check if weak entity contains a specific value in its list of records

Tags: mysql, sql

So what I'm trying to do is to check whether in a list of id_1's, does it contains a specific value in its list?

e.g. Does id_1 of 1 contain a val of 10? Both the id_1 and val columns are foreign keys.

```
id_1  val
1     2
1     10
1     3
2     2
2     3
```

I am able to get to this form above, but I don't have any idea on how to check whether id_1 contains a specific value in its list of val's. Some tips?

Comment: Just try to select it. If it's there you get it, otherwise not. For instance: `select * from mytable where id_1 = 1 and val = 10`.

Comment: Given that the two answers provided were different, I cannot see that both were correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, to just check for a *single* value, a simple select should work here:

```
SELECT id_1
FROM yourTable
WHERE val = 10  -- or whatever single value for which you want to check
```